# For a random walk in 3d with average step size a, what is the probability that a path of length L encloses a tube of radius R?

Tags: random-walk

These sort of questions pop up regularly in the research of a colleague at work.
He studies long polymer chains of length $L$ and carbon-carbon length $a$ that are in a
liquid.

What is the probability that such a polymer will go round a tube of radius $R$?
It is assumed that $a << R < L$.

The problem is not well posed, most probably. What else is necessary to answer?
(One could look for a path that is almost closed, within a distance $h$.)

Comment: Someone here might start by trying to answer a corresponding two dimensional question: a random walk in a plane with a missing disk.

Comment: it seems a lot easier to approach this problem using Montecarlo simulations that by direct analysis

Comment: Both comments are true. Is there any literature on this?